# Change which objects button control over time

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine, button

I am making a game where the player is able to only rotate the current tile that they are standing on. I'm using OnCollisionStay and Input.horizontal and vertical to achieve this now. It works great with the keyboard but my goal is to make it for mobile.

My question is how would I make UI buttons control the different tiles as the player moves. So basically I needs to switch which tile the buttons are controlling as the player moves to the next tile. Hopefully this makes sense. Right now each tile has it's own script. I've included one of them below.

Thank you!

```
void OnCollisionStay(Collision collision)
{
  if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Player")
  {
      float rotateright = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * rotatespeed;
    float rotateleft = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * rotatespeed;

    transform.Rotate(0, rotateright, 0);
    transform.Rotate(rotateleft, 0, 0);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using OnCollisionStay for functionality like this is not ideal.

For example, if your character object is overlapping two colliders at once, it will rotate both at the same time, resulting in all sorts of spatial chaos.

A better idea is to store the current tile in a public, class-scope variable, and operate on it via a separate function.  You can then use OnCollisionEnter to check for when a new tile has been entered.

Example:

```
GameObject currentTile;

void Update (){

    ControlCheck();

}

public void ControlCheck(){

    if (currentTile != null){

        // Rotation code goes here

    }

}

void OnCollisionEnter(Collision obj){

    currentTile = obj.transform.gameObject;

}
```